# AVD Button fail

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to learn programming. I am currently using eclipse. I have downloaded every sdk i need but still when I open the emulator were i have made a button this stands: Unfortunately countdowner has stopped. I have tried to restart the emulator. This is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button1, button2, button3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn60);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn90);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn5:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, _5.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.btn60:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, _60.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;
    case R.id.btn90:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, _90.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I tried to make the onClick in the xml file but the same happend so I tried a other way. Someone who know the problem?

Comment: It is not a problem with the AVD; when it says "Unfortunately... has stopped" it means a runtime error in your code has happened. Check the logcat output which details the error and post it here (look for text in red). If you don't know how to find that, in Eclipse use Window->ShowView->LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

```
`Unfortunately countdowner has stopped.`
```

means you have a runtime error with your application. Open the Logcat and post here what is the error it is displaying. You can do this by Selecting following in Eclipse

```
Window --> Show View --> LogCat
```

Based on the error, Post your code and Logcat, we should be able to help you out

Comment: I posted the code as a answear. It was to long for an comment

Answer (score 0):

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.epstudios.Countdowner/com.epstudios.Countdowner._60}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

You need to declare all activities that should be reachable with an `Intent` in the manifest.

Comment: I found the problem forgot to add this in the android Manifest:
<activity
            android:name="com.epstudios.Countdowner._5"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>

Answer (score 0):

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.epstudios.Countdowner/com.epstudios.Countdowner._60};
```

Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 
`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.epstudios.Countdowner/com.epstudios.Countdowner._60}` --> This clearly indicates that you've not declared your activity in the Manifest file.

Do the following :

1. Declare the Activity in the manifest file as per the above error message
2. Do Project --> Clean and Run
3. If you still find errors,...Post your manifest.xml along with with logcat errors